# Imported element GaugesModule gives 'radial-gauge' is not a known element error

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm trying to make a simple Gauge to work using Ionic (Capacitor) and ng-canvas-gauges.

I followed the steps for installing ng-canvas gauges (from here: http://www.wayneparrott.com/add-a-realtime-gauge-to-your-angular-project/) but I'm getting this error:

```
core.js:14965 NG0304: 'radial-gauge' is not a known element:
1. If 'radial-gauge' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'radial-gauge' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

`GaugesModule` is imported in `app.module.ts` like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { GaugesModule } from 'ng-canvas-gauges';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, GaugesModule],  
  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I was reading some similar posts and some suggested videos (Like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=za5NaFavux4) but I can't make it to run without errors. The solution suggested in the video gives me this new error:

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Unexpected value 'GaugesModule' declared by the module 'ComponentsModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.
Error: Unexpected value 'GaugesModule' declared by the module 'ComponentsModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation
```

`GaugesModule` import was removed from `app.modules.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This is my new `components.modules.ts` file:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { GaugesModule } from 'ng-canvas-gauges';

@NgModule ({
    declarations:[GaugesModule],
    exports:[GaugesModule]
})

export class ComponentsModule {}
```

And my `home.modules.ts` file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HomePage } from './home.page';

import { HomePageRoutingModule } from './home-routing.module';

import { ComponentsModule } from './components/components.modules';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    ComponentsModule,
    HomePageRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

ionic info:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.17.1 (/usr/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.7.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 12.1.4
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 12.2.5
   @angular/cli                  : 12.1.4
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 4.0.0

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI      : 3.2.2
   @capacitor/android : not installed
   @capacitor/core    : 3.2.2
   @capacitor/ios     : not installed

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.3
   native-run  : 1.4.1

System:

   NodeJS : v14.17.6 (/usr/bin/node)
   npm    : 7.23.0
   OS     : Linux 5.
```

Any help? Thanks

Comment: You have to import GaugesModule just on the module that you use. For example, if you are trying to use the Gagues on your home page, and it has a module.
Just import on your home.page.module.ts
Imports [ GaugesModule ]

Comment: That was the first thing I did. Doing that gives me two errors.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'update')
    at RadialGauge$1.basicUpdate (VM59 src_app_home_home_module_ts.js:299)
    at RadialGauge$1.initGauge (VM59 src_app_home_home_module_ts.js:279)
    at RadialGauge$1.ngAfterViewInit (VM59 src_app_home_home_module_ts.js:215)

Comment: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement')
    at RadialGauge$

Comment: But now, is a Gauges problem, not yours